# Figurative meaning of "to hose something" (not watering)

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have found some sentences where "hose <something>" is not used as literally watering.

Examples of this use I don't know:

> Ghostery completely **hosed** Firefox and I had to delete Firebox [and] download a fresh copy sans Ghostery
>
> **Hosed** my Firefox after Hardy install (more context [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=762430))
>
> I **hosed** my website (more context [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-hosed-my-website-help))

So, what does it mean that something get hosed in this context?

Comment: **[to hose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hose#Verb)** (sense 5) : (transitive, computing) To break a computer so everything needs to be reinstalled; to wipe all files.

Comment: Oh, so it was in an online dictionary, my fault (couldn't find it in Wordreference and gave up too soon). Thank you.

Comment: No problem! I became curious 'cause I did not know this sense too. Of the unorthodox uses of *hosed*, I was only acquainted with the antipodean "*home and hosed*". (0:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This meaning of "hosed" is figurative.  The metaphor is from when Bull Connor's government forces used fire hoses to control crowds of protesters, in the early 1960s.  (The early 1980s Polish government used the same tactic against Solidarity protesters.)  The spray from a firehose is very intense.

MIT students used this metaphor to describe the difficulty of their studies: "An MIT education is like [taking a drink from a firehose](http://hacks.mit.edu/Hacks/by_year/1991/fire_hydrant/)."

"Hosed" has since been used to describe episodes where a high-technology item is ruined, especially as a result of trying to install another high-technology item.

[The New Hacker's Dictionary](http://hackersdictionary.com/html/index.html) is a good reference for terms like "[hosed](http://hackersdictionary.com/html/entry/hosed.html)".